# Default argument for partial specialization [Clang yes, GCC no]

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, template-specialization

Why does the following compile with `clang` but not with `g++ 4.9`

```
#include <array>

template< typename T1, typename T2 , typename T3 = int>
struct A;

template<typename T, unsigned int N, typename T2, typename T3>
struct A< std::array<T,N>, T2,  T3 > {
    int a;
};

int main()
{
  A< std::array<int,10>, double>  a;
  a.a +=3;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7800f49ba5aac43

g++ does not find a suitable specialization and complains with "incomplete type". I am wondering since, the default argument `typename T3 = int` should apply for the specialization (or does it only apply for full specialization?)

Comment: Because you're using `unsigned int` instead of `std::size_t`. With the latter, both compilers accept the program.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21740896/

Comment: Could be https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16279

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The templates `A<T1, T2, T3>` and `A<T1, T2>` are not complete defined so you can't use your members, you can solve the problem defining this templates at this way:

```
#include <array>

template< typename T1, typename T2 , typename T3 = int>
struct A {
    int a;
};

template<typename T, unsigned int N, typename T2, typename T3>
struct A< std::array<T,N>, T2,  T3 > {
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    A< std::array<int,10>, double>  a;
    a.a +=3;
}
```

Another fine example of specialization more simple:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N>
struct A {
    T a = N;
};

template<unsigned int N>
struct A<int, N> {
    int a = 2*N;
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main() {
    A<float, 30> af;
    A<int, 30> ai;
    cout << af.a << endl << ai.a << endl;
}
```

Like @dys say's on your comment using `std::size_t` instead `unsigned int` works:

```
template< typename T1, typename T2 , typename T3 = int>
struct A;

template<typename T, std::size_t N, typename T2, typename T3>
struct A< std::array<T,N>, T2,  T3 > { 
        T3 a = N;
        int b; 
};

int main()
{
        A< std::array<int,10>, double>  a;
        a.a +=3;

        A< std::array<int,10>, double, int>  b;
        b.b +=3;
}
```

Comment: I dont think thats the answer,  the asnwer should be @dyp's comment.
The problem is that it matches the first prototype (which is incomplete yes) because the template matching is obviously pedantic about the used types -> ``template<typename T, std::size_t> std::array``

Comment: @dyp are really right, using `std::size_t` instead `unsigned int` works fine.