# Can a template parameter be both an int and an unsigned long?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
class A
{
};

template<int N, typename T> class B;

template<int N>
class B<N, A<N>>
{
};

int main()
{
    B<3, A<3>> b;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `B` is templated on an `int` while `A` is templated on `size_t`, which is an `unsigned long` with both compilers I am using.

When I use compiler 1 (current compiler), everything compiles and works the way I expect it to. When using compiler 2 (one we're moving to), I get a compiler error stating that there is no template specialization for `B` that takes an `unsigned long` - it has interpreted the `3` as an `unsigned long` as it needs to be one for `A`, but then can't find anything for `B`. The fix is obvious, - just change `B` to take a `size_t` as well (or change `A` to take an `int`) - but I was wondering which is strictly correct by the standard. My gut feel is that it's compiler 2 (the one that's throwing the error).

Comment: Exactly which compilers are you using? This info may be useful for others having your problem.

Comment: I didn't include it as it wasn't strictly relevant to the question, but "compiler 1" is GNU 6.2 and "compiler 2" is Intel 17.0

Comment: My guess is that if this works with one compiler but not with another, this may be a so-called implementation-defined issue.

Comment: FWIW, Clang does not match `B<3, A<3>>` to the specialization: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/foJKj2W66hK9bLAk

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/21740896/3953764

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest fix be `class B<N, A<size_t(N)>>` ? You're allowed to use constant expressions for non-type template parameters.

Comment: @MSalters: Yeah, that would be easier. I just included the first way to fix it that I thought of to ensure that I didn't get answers telling me "to fix the compiler error, do this" (I've gotten those answers before, even when I made it clear that wasn't the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [temp.deduct.type]:

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails.

`A<N>` for `N` is an `int` should fail deduction because the corresponding template parameter of `A` is actually `size_t`. This is a compiler #1 bug.

Comment: @MarcoA. It's [gcc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558976/can-a-template-parameter-be-both-an-int-and-an-unsigned-long/42559381?noredirect=1#comment72252298_42558976).