# Is array indexing constexpr or not ? GCC inconsistent?

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, c++11, constexpr

In his answer to my question
[Avoiding struct in variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21723799/avoiding-struct-in-variadic-template-function)
iavr remarked that "std::array::operator[] is constexpr only in C++14". My
question here is to make sure that GCC behavior is inconsistent and that's not
me wrongly understanding the standard.

I'm exploring different way of using some template meta programming to
initialize a two dimensional array to the Pascal triangle (with 0 outside). 
In the one I'm trying here, I want to avoid as much as possible to use 
template structure and in particular variadic in favor if constexpr function 
and arrays.

**Note for reader in a hurry: I'm putting the three following pieces of code for sake of
completeness but you dont need to understand them.**

---

I'm using the two following pretty standard definitions:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct Sequence {};
template<unsigned N, unsigned... Is> struct Range {
    typedef typename Range<N-1, N-1, Is...>::type type;
};
template<unsigned... Is> struct Range<0, Is...> {
    typedef Sequence<std::integral_constant<unsigned int, Is>...> type;
};
```

Then I have the following template constexpr function which given a line of
the triangle, compute the next one:

```
// nextline
template <typename... SeqTis, typename T, size_t Size>
constexpr std::array<T, Size>
nextline(Sequence<SeqTis...>, const typename std::array<T, Size> ar) {
  return { 1, (ar[SeqTis::value]+ar[SeqTis::value+1])... };
}
template <typename T, size_t Size>
constexpr std::array<T, Size>
nextline(const typename std::array<T, Size> ar) {
  return nextline(typename Range<Size-1>::type(), ar);
}
```

And the following add an element at the end of a partially initialized array:

```
template <typename... SeqTis, typename T, size_t Size>
constexpr std::array<T, Size>
appendarray(Sequence<SeqTis...>, const typename std::array<T, Size> ar, const T el) {
  return { ar[SeqTis::value]..., el };
}
template <size_t Pos, typename T, size_t Size>
constexpr std::array<T, Size>
appendarray(const typename std::array<T, Size> ar, const T el) {
  return appendarray(typename Range<Pos>::type(), ar, el);
}
```

---

In these code I'm using array indexing and it perfectly works. As you can try
with:

```
constexpr auto ar0 = std::array<int, 3> { 1,0,0 };
constexpr auto ar1 = nextline(ar0);
constexpr auto ar2 = appendarray<2>(ar1, 12);
for (auto i: ar2) std::cout << i << " "; // prints 1 1 12
```

But when I try to compile the following recursive struct:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
using Ar2  = std::array<std::array<T, N+1>, N+1>;

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t l> struct Loop {
  constexpr static Ar2<T, N> next() {
    return appendarray<l>(Loop<T, N, l-1>::next(),
                  nextline(Loop<T, N, l-1>::next()[l-1]));
  }
};

template<typename T, size_t N> struct Loop<T, N, 0> {
  constexpr static Ar2<T, N> next() {
    return Ar2<T, N>({ {1, 0} });
  }
};
```

};

Then GCC complains with

```
[...]
binom2.cpp:48:30: note: ‘static constexpr Ar2<T, N> Loop<T, N, l>::next() [with T = long long int; long unsigned int N = 10ul; long unsigned int l = 10ul; Ar2<T, N> = std::array<std::array<long long int, 11ul>, 11ul>]’ is not usable as a constexpr function because:

constexpr static Ar2<T, N> next() {
                              ^
binom2.cpp:50:38: error: call to non-constexpr function ‘std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type& std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::operator[](std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::array<long long int, 11ul>; long unsigned int _Nm = 11ul; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::reference = std::array<long long int, 11ul>&; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type = std::array<long long int, 11ul>; std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
  nextline(Loop<T, N, l-1>::next()[l-1]));
```

It seems that sometimes GCC allows constexpr array indexing, and sometimes it
doesn't. Am I missing something.

Comment: from what I understand, `T& std::array<T,N>::operator[]` is not constexpr, but `constexpr const T& std::array<T,N>::operator[] const` is...you have to manually cast anything that returns an std::array<T,N> with (const std::array<T,N>&)

Comment: Then it seems that GCC should accept my code since `Loop<...>::next()` is constexpr.

Comment: try `nextline(((const std::array<T,N>&)Loop<T, N, l-1>::next())[l-1])`. nextline returns a non-const std::array<T,N>, so you need to cast it to a const array.

Comment: Why is it so ? nextline are declared constexpr.

Comment: @hivert: at least in C++14, `constexpr` does not imply `const`.

Comment: @MadScienceDream : Ok ! Your diagnoses seems correct though the solution doesn't work for me. I got `invalid cast of an rvalue expression`

Comment: nextline is declared a constexpr, it returns a non-const std::array type. There are two [] operators in the class, a const version and a non-const version. The non-const version is not a constexpr  but a the const version is. However, the non-const operator will be selected by default. You MUST cast the array to get it to select the const [] operator.

Comment: @hivert Ah yeah, i remember now, the casting is weird, try `const_cast<const std::array<T, N>&&>(Look<T,N.l-1>::next())[l-1]`

Comment: `std::get<N>(std::array<..>&)` is `constexpr` (in C++1y) and returns a non-const reference. Not sure why `std::array::operator[]` is not constexpr for the non-const case.

Comment: @MadScienceDream : you where right, but confused with the types. The fixes is: `nextline(((const Ar2<T, N>&) Loop<T, N, l-1>::next())[l-1])` ! Thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: @dyp I believe the non-`const` `[]` is not `constexpr` only because the committee hasn't gotten around to it. There was a lot of work done immediately following C++11 release to make everything `constexpr` that could be ([N3469,70,71 all accepted in October 2012](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/)). Then the `constexpr` rules changed in October 2013 with the acceptance of [N3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) into the WP. The effect of those changes hasn't had time to percolate through the library yet (and won't before C++17).

Comment: [This ISO C++ Standard Discussion list thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/nrAu_YbCbYM/discussion) goes into detail specifically about the absence of `constexpr` on `std::array::operator[]` and the history behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand,

```
T& std::array<T,N>::operator[]
```

is not constexpr, but

```
 constexpr const T& std::array<T,N>::operator[] const
```

Is...you have to manually cast anything that returns an (non-const) std::array with (const std::array&) to get it to select the correect operator.

After some finagling with the cast syntax, it looks like the correct syntax is:

```
nextline(((const Ar2<T, N>&) Loop<T, N, l-1>::next())[l-1])
```

though you may still want to look into const_cast as the regular cast will remove the rvalue-ness of the function call.

Comment: You might clarify that `constexpr operator[]` for `array` is standard in C++1y, but an extension (hence non-portable) to the behavior specified in C++11. In C++11, `size`, `max_size`, and `empty` are the only `array` members required to be `constexpr` (per 23.2.1 [array.overview]/3).

Comment: @dyp Does `T&const&&` reduce to `T const&`?

Comment: @Yakk [No](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e879cd81f26e49e "Demo at Coliru"), but he did say "something like" ;)

Comment: By the way use `const_cast` instead of *C cast*

Comment: I can do [`as_const` with 2 overloads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/080f73523a591dec). Anyone find a simpler implementation?

Comment: @Casey Maybe `template<class T> typename std::conditional< std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const&, T const&& >::type as_const(T&& p) { return std::forward<T>(p); }`? But I like your version better ;)

Comment: @Casey Doesn't the second overload need a `std::forward`?

Comment: `tmeplate<typename T> using type_as_const = typename std::conditional< std::is_reference,T>::value, typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const&, T const>::type; template<typename T> type_as_const<T>&& as_const( T&& t ) { return std::forward<T>(t); }`?

Comment: @dyp [Err, yes.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77918d65632e18ac) That's what I get for testing in unevaluated contexts. [I prefer `move` to `forward`, since it isn't a universal refererence I feel it's less confusing.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a058ed2f8133e60). Maybe just give up and use `static_cast<const T&&>`?

Comment: Actually, replace `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type const&` with `typename std::conditional< std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, T const&, T const&& >::type`, so the traits class `type_as_const` works on all three of value, rvalue and lvalue types "perfectly".  You could also imagine the metaprogramming version that takes a type conversion operation and applies it to the underlying `T` value type, then rewraps the result in `&` or `&&` or nothing depending on what was there to start with.

Comment: `template< template<class>class transform, typename T> using transform_value_type_of = typename std::conditional< std::is_reference<T>::value, typename std::conditional< std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, transform<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>&, transform<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>&&>::type, transform<T>>::type;` then `template<typename T> using const_type_helper = const T; template<typename T> using as_const_type = transform_value_type_of< const_type_helper, T >;` -- more characters makes a solution better, right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to declare the `next` function to return a constexpr const array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t l> struct Loop {
  constexpr const static Ar2<T, N> next() {
    return appendarray<l>(Loop<T, N, l-1>::next(),
                  nextline(Loop<T, N, l-1>::next()[l-1]) );
  }
};
```